# Will I be able to install ubuntu touch on a Meizu MX4 with android?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, android, meizu-mx4

I'm thinking about buying [this Meizu MX4](http://www.amazon.it/Meizu-MX4-32GB-Telefono-Cellulare/dp/B00QLPCFOW/ref=sr_1_7?s=electronics&ie=UTF8&qid=1435278276&sr=1-7&keywords=Meizu+MX4) that comes with Android.

I was wondering if it would be possible to install Ubuntu Touch on it and keep receiving OTA updates. Being able to dual-boot it with android/ubuntu would also be nice.

Comment: According to [this news](https://twitter.com/ubuntu/status/613990736976080896) from Ubuntu twitter Meizu MX4 is now available with Ubuntu pre-installed.

Comment: I know, but a friend of mine is going to travel to Italy, and I can't except him to play the origami game and win, so I decided to go with the android version and see if I can install ubuntu touch on it.

Answer (score 1):

according to [this article](http://news.softpedia.com/news/buying-a-meizu-mx4-with-android-to-flash-ubuntu-is-not-a-good-idea-485495.shtml) it's not such a good idea.

Not all Meizu devices are unlocked, and even if they do, they have a different partition table scheme.

Answer (score 0):

This guy somehow managed to get it there: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qe9hKdYEMqY. I think if you are persistent about it, better to follow some tutorials on rooting the Chinese version of Meizu MX4 on XDA developers. As far as I know it is also possible to unroot it, so you would have a single boot with Ubuntu or with Android. In case if it is rewriting the architecture you would need to buy a new phone. Android phones come with a custom system partitioning, and rewriting the system multiple times even switching to CyanogenMod can result in boiling of your processor.

1. You need to backup your existing system.
2. You need to root your device.
3. You need to download the Ubuntu build for your device.
4. You need to burn it through your boot loader.
5. Turn on your phone and enjoy it!

The bootloader on Android is usually accessible through pressing VOLUME UP and POWER button. [This link](https://forum.xda-developers.com/meizu-mx/orig-development/rom-lineageos-14-1-meizu-m2-note-t3551287) seems like a good solution for building any OS into Meizu. In general it is also good to check with the Ubuntu community and ask questions there.